# Expand data after a table merge with conditionals

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have the following merge in power query on Power BI:

```
let  Data = Table.NestedJoin(União, {"cod_parceiro"}, Hierarquia, {"cod_parceiro"}, "Hierarquia", JoinKind.LeftOuter),     
#"Hierarquia Exp" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Data, "Hierarquia", {"grupo_de_loja", "nome_parceiro", "comercial", "regional", "potencial", "data_inicial", "data_final"}, {"grupo_de_loja", "nome_parceiro", "comercial", "regional", "potencial", "data_inicial", "data_final"})
in #"Hierarquia Exp"
```

Is it possible for me to put conditionals for the expansion to happen?

For example, I need it to only return values ​​from the "Hierarquia" table if:

the field [data_pagamento] of the table "União" is >= than the field [data_inicial] of the table "Hierarquia"
and
the field [data_pagamento] of the table "União" is <= than the field [data_final] of the table "Hierarquia"

If it does not meet the conditions, return NULL for all fields in the "Hierarquia" table in the merge

I've tried a few post-expansion alternatives, but they all result in the same issue:

There can be no data if it doesn't meet the conditions, they have to result in null

```
#"Coluna Condicional Adicionada" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colunas Reordenadas", "Condicao", each if [status] = "PAGO" or [status] = "ESTORNO" then
[data_pagamento] >= [data_inicial] and [data_pagamento] <= [data_final]
else
[data_digitacao] >= [data_inicial] and [data_digitacao] <= [data_final]),
#"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Coluna Condicional Adicionada", 
each [Condicao] <> false),`
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally expand columns, but after expanding, you can create new columns that show the conditional values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Between the merge and the expansion add a custom column to test your data

Here I testing data_pagamento against the merged results from Hieraquia.  Then afterwards, just remove the Hieraquia column and expand the new custom column

[image]

Or, expand as is, test, then filter the rows afterwards

Comment: Your resolution was the one that brought me closer, I believe that through it I can reach the result.

https://i.imgur.com/shXgx18.png

Here she found a problem, in the Hierarquia table, there are some codes that have more than one line with information, and I am trying to use the fields "data_inicial" and "data_final" to get only the correct line as a result, bringing the incorrect lines as null.

Following your step, it returns null because it compares with the first line and ignores the second one which would be correct

Comment: If you don't provide sample data that shows your inputs and desired outputs, we can only guess how your data is structured and what you want to do with it. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but here's an example of the two tables
(I don't know how to send a file here, but if I can, I'll send a .pbix with the examples included)

https://i.imgur.com/qFbJwYz.png
https://i.imgur.com/364eYuq.png

Unity - União
Hierarchy - Hierarquia
payment_date - data_pagamento
initial_date - data_inicial
final_date - data_final

Comment: The date condition is to get the corresponding cod_comer in that period, and if there is none that corresponds to the payment date, return null for all columns in the merge